# If the set of non-0 stalks of F is relatively open, is the same true of its Verdier dual?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, sheaf-theory, constructible-sheaves

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, $F$ a bounded complex of $\Bbb C_X$-modules with constructible cohomology. If the set $\{x: F_x\neq0\}$ is relatively open (i.e. open in its closure), is the same true of the set $\{x: (\operatorname{D}_X F)_x\neq0\}$? Here $\operatorname{D}_X$ is the Verdier dual functor.